# How to target entire Bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

That what I've managed to do so far

[image]

How can I target the entire navbar? I want everything to be blue.

P.S: Here is the CSS I added:

```
 .navbar-inner
{
    background-color: #3177D4;  
    /* remove the gradient */
    background-image: none;
    /* set font color to white */
    color: white;
}   

/* menu items */


        .navbar .nav > li > a {
          background-color: #3177D4;   
          color: white;

        }



    .navbar .nav > li > a:focus,
    .navbar .nav > li > a:hover {
      background-color: #3177D4;
      color: white;
    }
     
        .navbar .nav > .active > a,
        .navbar .nav > .active > a:hover,
        .navbar .nav > .active > a:focus {

          background-color: #3177D4;
          color: white;
        }

   

    .navbar .brand 
    {
        background-color: #3177D4;
        color: white;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-inner .container {
         background-color: #3177D4;
          background-image: none;
    }
    .navbar-inner {
    background-color: #3177D4;
          background-image: none;
    }
    div.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-fixed-top {
    background-color: #3177D4;
          background-image: none;
    }
```

Comment: How can we know and tell you what to target without the site or relevant HTML to reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.navbar
{
    background-color: #3177D4;  
    /* remove the gradient */
    background-image: none;
    /* set font color to white */
    color: white;
}
```

You can use "inspect element" to see what element to target.

Comment: .navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
background-color: #3177D4;
    background-image: none;
    border-bottom:0px;
}